# instantiateItem nor getItem are called on FragmentPagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragmentmanager

I've one activity with a viewpager with a custom FragmentAdapter.

Here is my adapter code:

```
this.viewPager.setAdapter(new FragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()) {
            SparseArray<WeakReference<Fragment>> registeredFragments = new SparseArray<>(4);

            @NonNull
            @Override
            public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
                Fragment fragment = (Fragment) super.instantiateItem(container, position);
                this.registeredFragments.put(position, new WeakReference<>(fragment));
                return fragment;
            }


            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return 4;
            }

            @Override
            public android.support.v4.app.Fragment getItem(int position) {
                WeakReference<Fragment> ret = this.registeredFragments.get(position);

                if (ret == null || ret.get() == null) {
                    if (position == 0)
                        ret = new WeakReference<>(new NewGiveawayStepFragment1());
                    else if (position == 1)
                        ret = new WeakReference<>(NewGiveawayStepFragment2.newInstance(getUser().getApiFacade().getProfilePicUrl()));
                    else if (position == 2)
                        ret = new WeakReference<>(new NewGiveawayStepFragment3());
                    else if (position == 3)
                        ret = new WeakReference<>(NewGiveawayStepFragment4.newInstance(getUser().getApiFacade().getProfilePicUrl()));
                }
                return ret.get();
            }
        });
```

The idea is after the fragments were created i store them into a `SparseArray` and avoid recreating them (i know i could have same behavior `viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit();` but it makes the activity take longer to load at first time

This idea was based on this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15261142/5679560

In a normal happy world everything works fine...

the problem is when user minimize the app -> android decides to saveState and close the app -> them user restores the app...

In this scenario when the user restores the app the pages `setOffscreenPageLimit` are never created

So let be more specific:
1-user loads activity
2-user loads viewpage 0
3-user minimizes the app and android close it
4-user restores the app OK
5-user goes to viewpage 1 OK
6-user goes to viewpage 2 `instantiateItem` is never called `getItem` is never called and a blank page is shown
7-user goes to viewpage 3 `instantiateItem` is never called `getItem` is never called and a blank page is shown

No exception is thrown. If the user leaves the app at page 1, when it restores page 0,1 and 2 are OK, if he leaves at page 3 then pages 2 and 3 are OK

This is my activity `onRestoreInstanceState`

```
  @Override
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        this.currentPage = savedInstanceState.getInt("currentPage");
        this.ignoreSpam = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("ignoreSpam", false);
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }
```

Absolutelly nothing special

Does anyone understand why this happens?

Comment: `FragmentPagerAdapter` never recreates Fragments (it keeps an array of Fragments itself), maybe you're thinking about `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`? You don't need any of this behavior if you're extending `FragmentPagerAdapter`.

Comment: I dont think... so how do you override the `getItem` method? since `FragmentPagerAdapter ` is an abstract class you must define this method

Comment: Yeah, but you'd just do your `if (position == 0)` checks and return a Fragment. It won't be called more than once per position.